# Dynamically determine audio container in Exoplayer

Tags: java, android, media, audio-streaming, exoplayer

I'm trying to use the ExtractorSampleSource to extract different audio files, some are .AAC some .M4A and some .MP3.  Is there a way to dynamically determine which extractor (AdtsExtractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor) without parsing the url string?  I don't want to parse the string as there is some text that I am not controlling, and cannot guarantee that '.aac' doesn't show up in the text.

Comment: maybe you can do it in a separate request with an HTTP HEAD request ? If you want I can post sample

Answer (score 1):

You can never know for sure without decoding the whole file. But we can get very confident. mp4 for example is broken down into 'boxes' if you find a valid box at the start of the file, It probably its an mp4. So for that we can check bytes 4-7 (0-3 are the atom size). If they are a know root atom type (ftyp,mdat, are most likely, but pdin, free and skip are possible), we PROBABLLY have an mp4. ADTS and MP3 both have the same syncword, so you will need to parse the entire header and check Whatever header seesm more 'sane' is your probable format. (ADTS http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=ADTS) (MP3 http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html) But note these types may have an ID3 tag the the start, so you will need to skip past that.